# WordPress Footer menu showing in the Top menu place

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming, wp-nav-menu-item

For some reason when I created a footer menu and the location as footer, it also shows up in the top menu location.

I have checked that both menus are set to their correct locations in the Admin -> Menu area and also checked my child theme code to ensure my navigation.php is pulling the correct wp_nav_menu which it is. What is also strange is when the site is in mobile mode, it shows the correct menu and isn't a problem.

I'm lost now as to what else to look into to solve this problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

(just let me know in the comments if you need any screenshots or more info)

Answer (score -1):

In the menu options, there is a checkbox as Display location to enable the location where that menu should place.

Please check the footer menu which has enabled both options Primary Menu &Footer Menu, If so uncheck the Primary menu checkbox.
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but this was mentioned in my question that I had already configured this setting and I am still getting the problem.